# How to estimate pose of Charuco Board on OpenCV 4.8.1?

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

In previous versions of OpenCV it was enough to call `estimatePoseCharucoBoard`. However, as of 4.8.1 that function is no longer supported. Documentation says to use `solvePnP`, altought provides no example for how that may be achived.

Does anyone have a working example of how to do it with the new pipeline?
Thanks in advance.

I was expecting to find up to date documentation in OpenCV

Comment: "use solvePnP" is the advice for single markers. for custom boards and charuco boards, the APIs still exist. ***up to date documentation exists:*** https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#ga21b51b9e8c6422a4bac27e48fa0a150b `estimatePoseCharucoBoard` is available in 4.8.1. I just tested that.

Comment: `estimatePoseCharucoBoard` does not exists in my package. Using opencv-python==4.8.1.78

Comment: what does `pip list` say, on a command line? relevant lines of the output contain "opencv".

Answer (score 1):

I've also just ran into this, it seems that `estimatePoseCharucoBoard` is in the `opencv-contrib-python` package rather than the base `opencv-python` one.